# How can I convert a ForEach into a For loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, for-loop, razor, foreach

I am working on displaying an amount of reviews after a rating, the code I wrote works, but I realized it ends up displaying the command for each review, so if there are two reviews I see "1 Review 1 Review."  I've been working on this for a while and am still a bit new to MVC, C#, etc, and cannot seem to figure out how to change this to a for loop that will count the ReviewCount and display it as a single line with 1 or more "reviews" indicated.  I tried spreading this out but then the local variable can't be called, and that's where I am stuck!

```
@foreach (var review in item.Campaign.Reviews)
    {

        int ReviewCount = 0;
        ++ReviewCount;
        if (ReviewCount > 1)
        {
            @Html.Raw(ReviewCount)
            @Html.Raw(" Reviews")
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.Raw(ReviewCount)
            @Html.Raw(" Review")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code does not make any sense. Do you even understand what it does?

Comment: Also, you are outputting your `ReviewCount` once per review while counting, which makes no sense either. If you want to count `Reviews`, just use `item.Campaign.Reviews.Count()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to count reviews, just use the LINQ `Count()` method:

```
@{ int ReviewCount = item.Campaign.Reviews.Count(); }
@Html.Raw(ReviewCount)
@if (ReviewCount != 1) {
    @Html.Raw(" Reviews")
}
else {
    @Html.Raw(" Review")
}
```

Also, be [DRY](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/keep-your-code-dry/).

Comment: Thank you!  I am glad you could make sense of what I was trying to do.  I'm still learning these commands so this is really appreciated!  It worked exactly as needed.